# Shamir's Scheme in C#

Tags: c#

I want to implement Shamir's Scheme in C# ,and I don't understand how can be obtained the secret, corresponding shares (I1 .. I5),
and how can be reconstructed secret ?

in exemple: 1.1 
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BzdtLhyvFABCNzllZGJjMjUtOGU2ZC00ZTRjLTg5NGMtMzcxYTU3MjEwZmNm

I think I1=8 from P(1) mod 11; but I2 = 10 != p(2) mod 11
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to implement it yourself: perhaps you're better off posting this question on: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ .

If you just want to do cryptography in C#: check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx